# Cannot Run Puppeteer (Chromium) on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I use headful chromium on Ubuntu.

This is my code:

```
const dmb ={
    browser: null,
    page: null,

    initialize: async(proxy) => {

        dmb.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        });

        dmb.page = await dmb.browser.newPage();
        await useProxy(dmb.page, `${proxy}`) //puppeteer-page-proxy
    },
```

This is the error I get:

```
 Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
0|app  | [5802:5802:0910/061800.233918:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1417)] Unable to open X display.
0|app  | [0910/061800.240245:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
0|app  | Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
0|app  | [0910/061800.242785:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
0|app  | Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
0|app  | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
0|app  |     at onClose (/root/igwebproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
0|app  |     at Interface.<anonymous> (/root/igwebproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:183:68)
0|app  |     at Interface.emit (events.js:326:22)
0|app  |     at Interface.close (readline.js:424:8)
0|app  |     at Socket.onend (readline.js:202:10)
0|app  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
0|app  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1244:12)
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21
```

I have already configured the requirements as per in the puppeteer troubleshoot guide.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

did you installed dependencies?

`sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget`

Comment: Yes, I did all of them

Answer (score 3):

First check if any dependencies are missing.

Go to:
`your_project_path/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux`
(this will also serve as a check if you have chromium installed)

Then run:
`ldd chrome | grep not`
(to see if any dependencies are missing)

For me (after I ran the installation from @Rhezashan) it turned out still be missing libgbm:
`libgbm.so.1 => not found`

You can install it with:
`sudo apt-get install libgbm-dev`