# Ubuntu 20.04: Error: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless

First of all I know this issue has been reported many times. I tried every possible solution and did not work for me
I ran this in Windows without an issue. But I recently switched to Linux and getting this error ,

I tried executablePath: `'/usr/bin/chromium-browser'` ,`args: ["--no-sandbox"],` `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']` , and reinstalling node_modules.
but nothing worked for me.
And here's the complete code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
let browsers = {
    browser: undefined,
    browserNoProxy: undefined,
    pageProxy: undefined,
    pageNoProxy: undefined
};


(async () => {
    browsers.browserNoProxy = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--start-maximized'],
        headless: false,
        executablePath: process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH || "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-706915/chrome-win/chrome.exe"
    });
    
    browsers.browser = browsers.browserNoProxy;
    
    browsers.pageProxy = await browsers.browser.newPage();
    browsers.pageNoProxy = await browsers.browserNoProxy.newPage()
    await browsers.pageProxy.goto("https://www.google.com");
    await browsers.pageNoProxy.goto("https://www.google.com");
})();

module.exports = browsers;
```

Comment: do you know where exactly your Chrome executable is? does `process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH` contain the right path? to me it seems defining `executablePath` is the problem. puppeteer would find chrome easily by itself (on linux and windows too) in the `node_modules` folder, by relying manually given path you are putting a single point of failure on browser launch.

Comment: @theDavidBarton yes. I just found the reason . Seems like chromium-browser missing some dependencies on my OS. Therefore I included default google-chrome path and now It's working!

Comment: great to hear! I suggest merging this question to an existing one which suggests installing the Debian dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Run Puppeteer (Chromium) on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823927/cannot-run-puppeteer-chromium-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)